# Data display issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to display data that includes multiple choice questions. I want my webapplication to display these questions and choices in label and radiobuttons when called for. The problem is that when i retrieve the data, i get the last question and its choices in the label and radio buttons. i want it to start from the first question and display next questions when the next button is clicked.need help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le3N0.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking for the concept of the functionality which you want to implement.
I have some suggestion as follows:

1. There should be link between Question and its choices.
2. You can bind linked data from database on the page with the help of radiobutton list

I mean this would be the simple approach which you an start with.Regarding your problem
that you are getting last data, in that case you can retrieve only one question and answer
on the page load and then after on th click on Next you can retrieve the second.

In that way you can get next data. For this you can create the stored procedure and can pass the
parameter on the click of Next button. On the basis of parameter you can fetch data from
database and bind to the page controls.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: appreciate ur response but it doesn`t help